# How to set `noRollbackFor` on a `TransactionTemplate`?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Given that I have a TransactionTemplate set up like below (where I start a new transaction within an existing transaction), how do I prevent the parent (`@Transactional`) transaction from rolling back when code inside the child transaction throws a specific exception? Essentially, emulating the `noRollbackFor` parameter of `@Transactional`.

```java
@Transactional
public void foo() {
    bar();
}

private void bar() {
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager);
    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

    transactionTemplate.execute(__ -> {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with a TransactionTemplate.
TransactionTemplate has no support for rollback rules.
See : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25086

> This is by design: TransactionTemplate does not support custom
> rollback rules. Technically TransactionTemplate isn't even aware of
> TransactionAttribute since that variant is an extended definition only
> supported by TransactionInterceptor (and therefore also living in the
> latter's package). The template operates on plain
> TransactionDefinition and uses fixed rollback behavior for all
> exceptions thrown from its callbacks, effectively RuntimeExceptions
> and Errors.
>
> Alternatively, you may use the PlatformTransactionManager directly:
> Inject it, call getTransaction on it, perform some resource
> operations, then call commit in a finally block... and handle
> potential runtime exceptions any way you need to, without calling
> rollback. You may also selectively handle the outcome, as long as you
> eventually call commit (or rollback, for that matter) to complete the
> transaction.

An alternative solution to have more control over what gets rollbacked and what's should fail is using savepoints, see https://dzone.com/articles/transaction-savepoints-in-spring-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear from your question, but note that if the exception is thrown inside the `transactionTemplate.execute()` method, **only the inner** transaction will be marked as rollback-only.
If you catch the exception e.g. in the `foo` method and don't let it bubble up to the outer transaction boundary, then the outer transaction still gets committed, while the inner was rolled back.

`noRollbackFor` is used to determine what happens to the *inner* transaction, i.e. whether it will be still committed, even though the lambda finishes with an exception.